# XML parsing in IOS Shows NULL value in label?

Tags: objective-c, ios, xml, nsxmlparser, nsmutablestring

i m doing XML parsing using NSXMLParserDelegate..I m getting null value when i print the value in label...I m using simple xml file got in an internet.You can check what is in that file too.anyone pls help..Here is my code

```
#import "xmlViewController.h"

@implementation xmlViewController
@synthesize label;

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Release any cached data, images, etc that aren't in use.
}

#pragma mark - View lifecycle

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    NSURL *url=[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://www.bonifacedesigns.com/tuts/xmltest.xml"]];
    receivedData=[[NSMutableData alloc]initWithContentsOfURL:url];
    dataParser=[[NSXMLParser alloc]initWithData:receivedData];
    dataParser.delegate=self;
    [dataParser parse];
}

-(void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict{
//    if(!xmlString){
//        
//    }else
//    {
//        [xmlString setString:@""];
//    }
  if([elementName isEqualToString:@"elements"])
  {
      xmlString=[NSMutableString alloc];
      [xmlString setString:@""];
  }

}
- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundCharacters:(NSString *)string
{
    xmlString= (NSMutableString *)[string stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]];
}
-(void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didEndElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName
{

        if([elementName isEqualToString:@"element"]){

            NSString *string=xmlString;
            [xmlArray addObject:string];
            label.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",xmlArray];

       }

}

@end
```

This is my XML file....I want to print XML Data Parsed! in my label.Help me with that.I have edited the code and check now

```
<elements>
<element myData="XML Data Parsed!"/>
</elements>
```

check this:

```
-(void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict{
//    if(!xmlString){
//        
//    }else
//    {
//        [xmlString setString:@""];
//    }


  if([elementName isEqualToString:@"elements"])
  {

      xmlString=[[NSMutableString alloc]initWithCapacity:5];
  }

}
- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundCharacters:(NSString *)string
{
    xmlString= (NSMutableString *)[string stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]];
}
-(void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didEndElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName
{

        if([elementName isEqualToString:@"element"]){
            [attributeDict objectForKey:@"myData"];
            [xmlString setString:@""];
            NSString *string=xmlString;
            [xmlArray addObject:string];
            label.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",xmlArray];

       }
```

I m getting error:

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Attempt to mutate immutable object with setString:'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x13ba052 0x154bd0a 0x1362a78 0x13629e9 0x1387970 0x2a26 0x9e1a35 0x5171532 0x9e002d 0x26b8 0xd764e 0x37a73 0x37ce2 0x37ea8 0x3ed9a 0xfbe6 0x108a6 0x1f743 0x201f8 0x13aa9 0x12a4fa9 0x138e1c5 0x12f3022 0x12f190a 0x12f0db4 0x12f0ccb 0x102a7 0x11a9b 0x2238 0x2195 0x1)
terminate called throwing an exception
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you have several errors in your code.

The mutable string `xmlString` isn't properly initialized, on the line :

```
xmlString = [NSMutableString alloc]; // wrong
```

This should look like : `xmlString = [[NSMutableString alloc] initWithCapacity:X];`.

Also, when the parser finds characters, you replace the entire existing mutable string, instead of appending them to the existing content, or try to because according to the code, you simply make a memory address compare and waste the result (`==`).

```
// wrong
xmlString == (NSMutableString *)[string stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]];
```

This should look like :

```
[xmlString appendString:[string stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]]];
```

Finally in `didEndElement`, I'm not sure what you are trying to achieve, but you add the string object reference to an array, and then set the label text to display the content of the array... as long as the mutable array is well allocated and initialized (what I'm really not sure), the label should display at least the array content.  But you might consider to "flush" the mutable string (`[xmlString setString:@""];`) and not allocate it on every element.

**EDIT** :

The `attributeDict` maps attribute names as the keys with their values. I guess your attribute value can be accessed via `[attributeDict objectForKey:@"myData"];`.

Comment: [xmlString setString:@""]; where to add this line..I have added that in my code.check is that correct?

Comment: add that in `didEndElement`. see my edit to handle attributes

Comment: ok but `setString` must be written **after** you do something with the string...also are you sure you *really* have a mutable string ?

Comment: i m sure having mutable string..i initialized in interface file...if i dont i will get an error..then what should i do with the string?(setString must be written after you do something with the string)

Answer (score 1):

I guess that the problem is in this line:

```
xmlString== (NSMutableString *)[string stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]];
```

Change `==` to `=`

Hope that explanation isn't needed.